# How to check if someone has a certain role

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

Ok, I know that there are similar questions out there but no matter what I try I get the same result. I have been trying for 2 days now to figure out how to check if I had the "OverBot-Admin" role for a ban command. But whenever I run the command it spams the chat! Here is my code:

```
      if (command === "ban") {
    if(message.member.roles.has(role => role.name === "OverBot-Admin")) {
      let reason = args.slice(1).join(" ");
      if (!reason) reason = "No reason provided";
      const user = message.mentions.users.first();

      if (user) {
        const member = message.guild.member(user);

        if (member) {
          member
            .ban({ reason: "They were being bad." })
            .then(() => {
              message.reply(
                ":white_check_mark: Successfully banned " +
                  message.user.id +
                  "for " +
                  reason
              );

              const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
                .setTitle("Ban")
                .addField("Member:", message.user.id)
                .addField("Reason:", reason)
                .setTimestamp()
                .setFooter(
                  "Created by OverThrow, OverBot SE",
                  "https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/649431468254429224/0b63291c1e7342c2320ca5c3cce806ca.png?size=2048"
                );
            })
            .catch(err => {
              message.reply(":x: I was unable to ban that member!");

              console.error(err);
            });
        } else {
          message.reply(":x: That user isn't a member to this guild!");
        }
      } else {
        message.reply(":x: You didn't mention a member to ban!");
      }
    }
  } else {
    message.reply(":x: I couldn't ban this user, please make sure you have the OverBot-Admin role!")
  }
```

Comment: Is the member at least being banned correctly?

Comment: Yes it ban's the member without the if statement that checks for the role.

Answer (score 0):

`message.member.roles.has()` requires a *role ID* as an argument, whereas here, you are passing in a function. The method I think you are looking for is [Collection.exists](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Collection?scrollTo=exists) (although this method is deprecated, if anyone can figure out a different way to go about this, please let me know).

Looking at the `message.reply` in the `then` function after banning, I see a `message.user.id`. However, `message.user` does not seem to be a valid property of the message object according to the docs. I assume that you would be referring to the user who was just banned, in which case you can reuse the `user` or `member` variable you previously defined.

If you have further problems, feel free to comment back.